# Use VBA to find submenu element and click

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am fairly new to vba and am self taught but have gotten my vba to log in to my website and get to the homepage. Next I need to click on a submenu item but I am struggling to find it. When manually doing this, the submenu works when I hover over the icon and the click on a button called "Comed Reports" below which I believe is the element ID "Report1017".

Below is the html code from the website:

[image]

And below is where my code is at this stage:

```
Sub Login()
    Const Url$ = "examplewebsite.com"

    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Navigate Url
        .Visible = True
    
        Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
      
        Set HTMLDoc = ie.Document        
        
        Dim Login As Object
        Dim Password As Object
        Dim LoginButton As Object
    
        For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
            If oHTML_Element.Name Like "txt_1*" Then Set Login = oHTML_Element
            If oHTML_Element.Name Like "txt_2*" Then Set Password = oHTML_Element
            If oHTML_Element.Name Like "btnLogin*" Then Set LoginButton = oHTML_Element
        Next

        Login.Value = ""
        Password.Value = ""
        LoginButton.Click
        
        Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        ' Find Submenu Report1017 here
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it always the id `Report1017` or does that id change after you reload the page?

Comment: It is always Report1017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is always `Report1017` you probably just need to run the javascript:

```
HTMLDoc.parentWindow.execScript "LoadContent('Report1017','ReportList.aspx?ReportParam=1017')", "JavaScript"
```

Give it a try.

Comment: This worked with a small change. I didnt need to run the second line you had and I had to call this action using the following: Call HTMLDoc.parentWindow.execScript("LoadContent('Report1017','ReportsList/ReportList.aspx?ReportParam=1017')", "JavaScript")

Comment: @MrNelson Sorry my fault. But yes either `Call` or remove the parenthesis. I fixed it.